# How to get filename when loading data

Tags: azure-synapse, openrowset, polybase

I'm using Azure Synapse/SQL Pools/Data Warehouse (insert any other brand names I may have missed!) to load data from Azure blob store.

I'm doing this via an external table using polybase.

I want to capture the source file for each row of data.

I've tried to test using `OPENROWSET`, but this does not appear to work

```
SELECT
*,
    x.filename() AS [filename]
FROM  
    OPENROWSET(
    WITH (
            DATA_SOURCE = [Analytics_AzureStorage],
            LOCATION = N'2022/06/21',
            FILE_FORMAT = [CompressedTSV]
        ) 
    ) x
```

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Parse error at line: 5, column: 5: Incorrect syntax near 'OPENROWSET'.

How can I load the filename to a table in the Azure Warehouse Synapse Pool?

Edit:

> The OPENROWSET function is not supported in dedicated SQL pool.

which explains why it does not work, is there a COPY/Polybase equivalent command for getting the file name?

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong. WITH should come later.
Have a look at the syntax here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-openrowset

```
OPENROWSET  
( { BULK 'unstructured_data_path' , [DATA_SOURCE = <data source name>, ]
FORMAT= ['PARQUET' | 'DELTA'] }  
)  
[WITH ( {'column_name' 'column_type' }) ]
[AS] table_alias(column_alias,...n)
```

Comment: It turns out Openrowset is not supported! Thanks for the link. 

The OPENROWSET function is not supported in dedicated SQL pool.